# Template markup and styling disappears when using pagination

Tags: php, wordpress, pagination

I'm trying to create a pagination in my custom wordpress theme but I can't wrap my head around a problem. Basically what I've got is a custom page template called "Portfolio Page" which resides in `page-portfolio.php`, I show a maximum of 5 posts per page.

When I click to go to the next page which contains either older or newer posts, I come to the url of `portfolio/page/page-number-here/` while the original url is `portfolio/`, which have all the markup and stuff. This causes all markup and styling to disappear when the url is no longer at `portfolio/`. How do I make it so that the older or newer posts loads into the same template?

I've been searching the codex and support for an answer but I can't even find anyone else that has this problem. I'm pretty sure I've missed something important which causes this to happen.

Here's my `page-portfolio.php`:

```
<?php /* Template Name: Portfolio Page */ ?>

<?php get_header(); ?>

<?php

  $num_posts = ( is_front_page() ) ? 1 : 5;

  $args = array(
    'post_type' => 'portfolio',
    'posts_per_page' => $num_posts
  );

  $query = new WP_Query( $args );
?>

<section id="portfolio-wrapper">
  <ul id="portfolio-list" class="list-reset">

  <?php if ( $query->have_posts() ) : while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post(); ?>

    <li class="clear-fix portfolio-piece">
      <h1 class="portfolio-piece-title"><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
      <div class="portfolio-piece-gallery"><?php the_field('images'); ?></div>
      <div class="portfolio-piece-content"><?php the_content(); ?></div>
    </li>

  <?php endwhile; ?>

  </ul>
  <div class="pagination-wrapper">
    <?php 
      if ( function_exists( 'pagination' ) ) {
        pagination( $query->max_num_pages );
      } 
    ?>
    <?php endif; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
  </div>
</section>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

And I'm using a pagination function which looks like this:

```
function pagination( $pages = '', $range = 4 ) {  

   $showitems = ( $range * 2 ) + 1;  

   global $paged;

   if ( empty( $paged ) ) {
     $paged = 1;
   }

   if ( $pages == '' ) {

     global $wp_query;

     $pages = $wp_query->max_num_pages;

     if ( !$pages ) {
       $pages = 1;
     }
   }   

   if ( 1 != $pages ) {

     echo "<div class=\"pagination\"><span>Page ".$paged." of ".$pages."</span>";

     if ( $paged > 2 && $paged > $range+1 && $showitems < $pages) { 
       echo "<a href='".get_pagenum_link( 1 )."'>&laquo; First</a>";
     }

     if ( $paged > 1 && $showitems < $pages ) {
       echo "<a href='".get_pagenum_link( $paged - 1 )."'>&lsaquo; Previous</a>";
     }

     for ( $i = 1; $i <= $pages; $i++ ) {
       if ( 1 != $pages &&( !( $i >= $paged + $range + 1 || $i <= $paged - $range - 1 ) || $pages <= $showitems ) ) {
         echo ( $paged == $i ) ? "<span class=\"current\">".$i."</span>":"<a href='".get_pagenum_link( $i )."' class=\"inactive\">".$i."</a>";
       }
     }

     if ( $paged < $pages && $showitems < $pages) {
       echo "<a href=\"".get_pagenum_link( $paged + 1 )."\">Next &rsaquo;</a>";
     }

     if ($paged < $pages - 1 &&  $paged + $range - 1 < $pages && $showitems < $pages) {
       echo "<a href='".get_pagenum_link($pages)."'>Last &raquo;</a>";
     }

     echo "</div>\n";
   }
}
```

Comment: You got a url we can scope?

Comment: are you getting a 404 on the subsequent pages?

Comment: @johnnyd23 No that's the weird part..

Answer (score 0):

There are a few issues that could be causing the problems you're experiencing. Firstly, it's a well documented issue in wordpress to have a page and a post type share the same slug - 'portfolio' in your case. One simple workaround here since you're using a custom template instead of an archive template for this post type, is to disable the archive for the portfolio post type when you register it -

```
'has_archive' => false
```

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type

I would also flush your rewrite rules after changing this by re-saving permalink settings to be certain this is not causing any issues.

Also, pagination will not work properly if you dont include the paged variable in your query. Declare it first, then include in your query:

```
$paged = ( get_query_var('paged') ) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
$args = array(
    'post_type'      => 'portfolio',
    'posts_per_page' => $num_posts,
    'paged'          => $paged,
);

$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Pagination_Parameters

Comment: I still get the same issue :(